# Tool for solving complicated system of equations.

Tags: linear-algebra

$$v_x=\frac{bn_xc+n_yv_zd-n_zv_yd-F_x}{a}$$
$$v_y=\frac{bn_yc+n_zv_xd-n_xv_zd-F_y}{a}$$
$$v_z=\frac{bn_zc+n_xv_yd-n_yv_xd-F_z}{a}$$

Given these equations, is it possible to solve them, also is there a program / online tool that can do it for me?

Solving in this scenario means only having the terms $v_x$, $v_y$ and $v_z$ on the left hand side of the three equations.

Please provide some tool because these equations might change.

Comment: What are the variables?

Comment: The $v$ terms, ex $v_x$.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [SymPy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html) because I am already familiar with Python.  SymPy offers algebraic (symbolic) solutions, too.  You can use [Sage](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/tour_linalg.html), too.  Sage need not be installed as you can use it in your browser.  You can of course solve it manually through [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination).

Answer (score 1):

Yes; you have a system of three linear equations in three variables. Simply apply Gaussian elimination. Explicitly, moving all the constants to one side, you get
$$\begin{pmatrix}
-a&-n_zd&n_yd\\
n_zd&-a&-n_xd\\
n_yd&n_xd&-a
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
v_x\\v_y\\v_z
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
bn_xc-F_x\\
bn_yc-F_y\\
bn_zc-F_z
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 0):

A very good tool, I recommend you is WIMS that you can find here: http://wims.unice.fr/wims/en_tool~linear~linsolver.en.html Another very good tool is Symbolab that you can download as application for your mobile device: https://www.symbolab.com/mobile.html?OS=Android&redirect=

Comment: I do know about wolfram but it does not accept only letters when solving a system of equations

Comment: @fullnitrous: see my edits. Sorry.